# Is there an efficient way to initialize a fixed array in Go without polluting the package namespace?

Tags: go

Here's an implementation of a type which stores a syslog Facility value:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

// Facility - as defined in RFC 5424
type Facility uint8

var facilityName []string = []string{
    "kernel",
    "user",
    "...",
    "local7",
}

func (s Facility) String() string {
    if int(s) < len(facilityName) {
        return facilityName[s]
    } else {
        return fmt.Sprintf("facility(%d)!", int(s))
    }
}

func UnknownFacility() Facility {
    return Facility(1) // "user"
}
```

The problem with this is that it puts it puts `facilityName` in the package namespace. The alternative is to create this array or slice inside the String() function, but this creates a new slice/array on every call to `String()`. The generated code isn't efficient.

Is there a way of doing this efficiently and not polluting the namespace?

`UnknownFacility()` also feels like Hungarian Notation...

Comment: Simply put it into the String() function. It *assigns* the `facilityName` from the slice literal by initializing the slice header, it does not create a slice element by element.

Comment: *and not polluting the namespace* — if the identifier is unexported, namespace pollution isn't much of a concern. The standard library also has lookup tables declared as package-level unexported `var`s, or protobuf generated code with `*_proto_rawDesc` byte slices

Comment: If IDE autocompletion becomes too wild, you can collect these package-level variables in a big struct at the cost of lengthier expressions.

Comment: @BurakSerdar I looked at the code generated by putting the literal inside the String() function and it seems to do a lot of work initializing structures on each function call... or am I missing something?

Comment: @blackgreen it isn't a concern until you manage to mistype an identifier in one file and have it match a similarly named variable defined in another file in code written by someone else... :-(

Comment: @MZB, it will do some work, but that should be a fixed amount of work. It should not depend on the number of elements in the slice.

Comment: As already mentioned before: namespace pollution is not a concern. The symbol is not exported.

Comment: @BurakSerdar here's the generated code for an up to 16 element slice https://godbolt.org/z/TGPE75Kdf - complexity depends on the number of elements in the slice. Above 16 elements it changes strategy and the code isn't as easy to follow.

Comment: @MZB, you are right. I stand corrected. It is initializing it one by one. Based on this, I suggest you don't worry about namespace issues and declare it as global.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer seems to be No.

1. The Go compiler (1.18.2) doesn't optimize creating a "constant" array / slice in a function, and there's no equivalent in Go of a C/C++ static variable. Such arrays therefore need to be stored in a package variable to avoid the overhead of recreating them on every function call. (See https://godbolt.org/z/TGPE75Kdf for example compiler output).
2. There's no mechanism to limit the visibility of a variable to a limited number of functions inside a package. (Go lacks an equivalent to a C++ anonymous namespace)

I'm working around this with a naming convention of prefixing variable names which only need file scope with *_filename* so they can't collide and are easy to distinguish in IDE auto-completion.

Whether adding variable names which only need file or function scope to the internal package namespace is a significant concern is a different question.

Comment: You can use `[...]string{}` instead, in that case. Since `[...]` is one array, I think it will be optimized.